# How can I display windows 11 notifications up top in the middle of the screen (without top taskbar)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I know it's possible to display it in the top corners, but is it possible to have it in the middle?

I tried this from someone on Github:(https://github.com/SamarthCat/notifications-at-top)

Works wonders for the corners, but not for the middle.

Windows officials say it's impossible, but coders have done it, which is funny. Perfect example here: https://github.com/SamarthCat/notifications-at-top

Comment: Seems like this specific line of code would have what you're looking for, from the link you provided: `SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - NotifyRect.Width, -50, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how can I run the code? I can't edit the code inside the executable. Can you help me please?

Comment: @KarlosTranda: You mustn't edit the code inside the executable!, but you have to download the github code, change `topnotify.cs` per your needs (see my answer if you please) and compile a new executable. Then you can add a shortcut to it in %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup if you want it to run on boot

Comment: @Marco: how do I compile a new exe?

Comment: Create a new console app and place the code in Main function. Or create a function and call it from Main, as you please

Comment: Would you kindly check this 1 min video if it's the correct one for compiling an exe? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SradgYcI2bQ

Comment: I don't understand: you told me you were trying with VSCode, so why do you try to run csc manually via cmd? Using VSCode, create a new console app, alter the code per your needs and compile, that's all.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: Ok. I'll do that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code carefully and try to understand how it works.
In short:

1. Notification window gets measured into `NotifyRect`
2. Notification windows is moved to a specific point of the screen using `SetWindowPos`

Taking a look at [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) definition

```
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(
       IntPtr hWnd, 
       int hWndInsertAfter, 
       int x, int Y, 
       int cx, int cy, 
       int wFlags);
```

we can see that it moves the window identified by `hWnd` to (x,y) position of the screen and it's also given (cx,cy) dimension; `flags` are used to alter the behaviour of the function and `SWP_NOSIZE` retains the current size (so cx and cy parameters are ignored).

Please alno note that `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` provides main screen size.

That said you could try to use this:

```
int xpos = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - NotifyRect.Width) / 2;
int ypos = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - NotifyRect.Height) / 2;
SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 
             xpos, ypos, 
             0, 0, 
             SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```